# jqplot custom marker in single series

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am in the process of developing a line chart for vehicle time table. In the chart X-axis showing the Time & Y-axis showing the Stops.

This line-graph show a vehicle going from the source (Stop-1) to the destination (Stop-2). In between two trips there is a buffer time like (5 min or 10 min). So for these buffer time I have data points for each (like- ['10:10AM', 'Stop-B']). I am using markers for showing the data points in the series.
But all the markers of a single series are same size and design. As per my requirement the buffer data points should not show the markers or the design of these buffer markers should be different from the trip markers.

Any solutions or help to my queries are highly appreciated.

Thanx
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Not a final plug and play solution, but a clue would be to try the axisTickRenderer formatString option.

I am pretty sure that you could use something like :

```
xaxis:{
    //Your other options here
    tickOptions:{
        formatString: function(){
                                  if(condition == 1) 
                                       return '<span style="color:red;">%0.1fV</span>'
                                  else 
                                       return '<span style="color:blue;">%0.1fV</span>'
                      }
    }
}
```

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-axisTickRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer.formatString